# How to find source of random spikes in network usage?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I am on AWS Ubuntu 14.x and this is our network usage in last 2 hours.

[image]

It seems to be very choppy with random spikes which is bringing down the site. I looked into Munin but that is of not much use.

How can I find the source of these random Network I/O spikes ?

Comment: I don't think these graphs show what you think they show. They don't look that choppy for a site unless it's getting millions of daily pageviews, and 5 MB in a ~5 minute period is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[VPC Flow logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) allow you to trace network traffic in your VPC. If you set that up you will have all the information you need. The link above is to the documentation which will tell you everything you need to know, there's no point me copying it in here.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `iftop` output to track down exact process which causes bandwidth spikes.
Next you might use either VPC Flow logs as Tim suggested or `tcpdump` to capture traffic on the specific port/interface and analyze this dump with Wireshark.